# What does やや書 indicate?

Tags: dictionary

What does the "marker" (?) **やや書** used in Japanese-English dictionaries indicate?

In addition how would you pronounce the phrase when citing someone a definition from a dictionary? やや書{しょ}? やや書{かき}?

I cannot pinpoint any pattern in below examples and I can't find a definition of the phrase itself. Trying to devise its literal meaning "usually in writing" (?) does not really match the examples (why "insecure" would be marked as a written form?)

> ときの声を上げる
> :  shout [**｟やや書｠** raise] a war cry.
>
> [2] 疑わしい doubtful
> :  （不確実な） uncertain; （不安定な） unsteady, **｟やや書｠** insecure; （信用できない） unreliable.
>
> やや
> : 〖少し〗a little, ｟話｠ a (little) bit; 【少しばかり】slightly; 【いくぶん】rather (!控えめにいってかえって意味を強める) , **｟やや書｠** somewhat (!rather より客観的な語) ; 【ある程度まで】to some extent.
>
> さしおく 差し置く
> : (意図的に無視する) ignore, **(やや書)** disregard; (そのままにしておく) leave.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this sort of question, you should check the 凡例 of the dictionary.

The [Wisdom E-J](http://www.sanseido.net/main/dictionary/hanrei/wisdomEJ.aspx) defines 話 and 書 like this:

```
　〔話〕　　　(話し言葉(spoken))
　〔書〕　　　(書き言葉(written))
```

The [Wisdom J-E](http://www.sanseido.net/main/dictionary/hanrei/wisdomJE.aspx) defines them like this:

```
　〔話〕　　　口語
　〔書〕　　　改まった語，文語
```

But I think the abbreviations must still come from 話し言葉 and 書き言葉, in any case.

So in this case, I think `書` is a dictionary-specific abbreviation indicating `書き言葉` 'written language'.  They're suggesting that the English translation marked with `やや書` is a bit more characteristic of written language than spoken.

Comment: To make it longer, I added a sub-question :)